# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, INSERT INTO, php

Tags: php, firebird

I have been looking for answers everywhere but just can't find out why I keep getting parse error for this line.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO NIMET(NIMI) VALUES("$_POST['fname']")";
```

Can anyone tell me why this line gets a parse error?

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on how to use strings in PHP. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Good thing that doesn't work. That is wide open to SQL injections.  The error tells you everything you need to know, `$_POST['fname']` is unexpected as is. You take off the `"`s and use it as a complex variable `{}` but you shouldnt do that either. Parameterize the query.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.` To concatenate two strings like this :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO NIMET(NIMI) VALUES(".$_POST['fname'].")";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO NIMET(NIMI) VALUES(".$_POST['fname'].")";
```

You need to use `.` to combine strings.

There is also a fanzy way, but for that you need a new enough version from PHP:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO NIMET(NIMI) VALUES({$_POST['fname']})";
```

I think the php-version you need for that is either 5.3 or 5.6. But I'm not shure about that.

Beside that: You shouldn't insert any unvalidated data from `$_POST` or `$_GET` into your DB. This could be used to insert malicious code.